# Is there possible way to create voting system without using php?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m newer to web development and learning something about web development.

I have been created simple web page using only html, css and scripts.

Now i need place rate it button under the image... and if we click the rate it button, it shows "#num user voted.. including you".,

so that, these task have to be done only using html,css and jquery...

When i googled,, all search contents are including php.

So anybody guide me?.. any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make any sense you'll need some sort of server involvement. It doesn't have to be PHP.

Comment: So that... what i have to do ? Thanks.

Comment: You could use some third party backend solution something like [parse.com](http://parse.com) or [nobackend.org](http://nobackend.org/). Short answer You need some backend to store data (in file or db)

Comment: i just confused, with these parse.com and nobackend.org .. thanks.. may i know, how to use?

Comment: There is documentation in both of these...

Answer (score 0):

Please consider, Javascript is **always and only** executed at client-side.
Given that, you'll need a server-side script to store data from votings (which is for example php).

Comment: I wouldnt say Javascript is always and only executed at client-side say for ex- nodejs ? :)

Comment: May i know.. which server side script suitable for me?? Thanks.

Comment: @Alok Swain: I knew that I'll get this response :)

Comment: @selva: any other script language is fine, e.g. if your server supports Python. Php is just the most common one for webapplications.

Comment: thanks @Toni.. but my goal is to achieve create a website only using html,css and jqueries

Comment: A poll generates data. How do you want to store/manage this data?